# Get the percentage of the day that has elapsed

Tags: javascript, html, clock

I need to get the percentage of the day that has elapsed in 24 hour time. 24:00 being 100%, 12:00 being 50%, and 00:00 being 0%. Here is what I have, however, the percentage is wrong:

```js
function currentTime() {
  let date = new Date(); 
  let hh = date.getHours();
  let mm = date.getMinutes();
  let ss = date.getSeconds();
  let ms = date.getMilliseconds();
  let session = "AM";

  if(hh === 0){
      hh = 12;
  }
  if(hh > 12){
      hh = hh - 12;
      session = "PM";
  }

  hh = (hh < 10) ? "0" + hh : hh;
  mm = (mm < 10) ? "0" + mm : mm;
  ss = (ss < 10) ? "0" + ss : ss;

  let time = hh + ":" + mm + " " + session;

  document.getElementById("clock").innerText = time; 
  let t = setTimeout(function(){ currentTime() }, 1000);

  percentage = (hh / 36 + mm / (60 * 24)) * 1000;

  document.getElementById("percentage").innerText = percentage; 
}

currentTime();
percentage();
```

```html
<div>
    <span id="percentage" onload="percentage()"></span>% elapsed
</div>
```

I would like to understand what I'm doing wrong and how this can be corrected. Thanks.

Comment: (As a percent) `(Date.now() - (new Date()).setHours(0,0,0,0)) / 864000`

Comment: @Tibrogargan I'm not sure I understand this.

Comment: Put that in your console and run it.  `Date.now()` returns the current time as the number of milliseconds since the UNIX Epoch.  `new Date()` gives you a `Date` object, on which you set hours, minutes, seconds, and milliseconds to 0 using `setHours` (i.e. midnight), which also returns the number of milliseconds since the UNIX Epoch.  Then you subtract the two and take the result as a fraction of a day.

Comment: @Matt it creates a date object with the hours, minutes, seconds and milliseconds set to 0, subtracts that from the current date, which returns the difference in milliseconds and divides that by the number of ms in a day to get the percentage. There is an implicit multiplication by 100, which is why it's divided by 684000 instead of 68400000

Comment: @Matt the answer I posted is pretty much the same as Tibrogargan's comment, just more explicit. Hopefully that will help clear up confusion.

Answer (score 1):

So, I'd reccomend forgoing the whole logic of hours and minutes and stuff.

You could simply say:

```js
function getDatePercent() {
  let dateInQuestion = new Date(Date.now())

    //we are copying the value of the date object into a new object:
    let startOfDay = new Date(dateInQuestion.valueOf())
    
    //define the beginning of the day. Depending on time zone and browser, this may need tweaking:
    startOfDay.setHours(0)
    startOfDay.setMinutes(0)
    startOfDay.setSeconds(0)
    startOfDay.setMilliseconds(0)

    let lengthOfDay = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 //ms in a day

    //subtract to find time since beginning of the day, divide by
    //number of ms in day, and then multiply by 100 to get percentage
    return ( dateInQuestion.valueOf() - startOfDay.valueOf() ) / lengthOfDay * 100
}

console.log(getDatePercent())
```

This allows us to more directly measure how many ms have eslapsed since the start of the day compared to how many ms there are in the day.

Note: this snippet was running based on UTC time, not local time. That's why I didn't originally make it a snippet. Someone edited my answer.